# How can I sort and limit with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made an review app with Express and Mongoose. I have an review model like below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ReviewSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    rating: Number
}, {
    timestamps: true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', ReviewSchema);
```

In my controller I just get all reviews list as below. But now I want to get a list with 10 recently reviews & sort by (orderby timestamps). How can I do it with mongoose? Please help me! I am a newbie with NodeJS and Mongodb.

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    console.log("Fetching Review...")
    // Retrieve and return all reviews from the database.
     Review.find(function(err, reviews){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send({message: "Some error occurred while retrieving Review."});
        } else {
            res.send(reviews);
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: Try this `Review.find({}).sort({ createdAt: 1 }).limit(10)`

Comment: It's not work, Anthony Winzlet

Answer (score 21):

This should work for you:

```
Review.find()
  .sort({_id: -1})
  .limit(10)
  .then(reviews => {
    console.log(reviews)
  });
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. You should mark the answer so hopefully it could help others.

Answer (score 6):

you can try like this :

```
Review.find({}, function(err,reviews){}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10);
```