mongoose: how can i find the first 10 documents with the highest number in a field
I have a mongoose model with a field played_frequency, how can i find the first 10 documents in all the documents having the highest number in the play
This is my model interface:
export interface ITrack {
  genre: string;
  title: string;
  artist: string;
  featuring?: string;
  duration: string;
  coverImage?: string;
  image: string;
  url: string;
  trending?: number;
  played_frequency: number;
  promoted?: boolean;
  likes?: number;
}

and the played_frequency, would vary between documents, i need a way to search all documents and find only 10 of the highest played_frequency.

.find().sort({ played_frequency: -1 }).limit(10)

really ? that easy ? let me try that right away. thanks a lot for the fast response too :)

Yeah, that's too obvious. Voting to close: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

Jeez! it works, thanks a lot, can you please explain how it works ?, especially the -1 part, i don't understand that part

@user3118363 thats the direction whether ascending or descending

lol, so easy, thank you so so very much.

something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014457/how-can-i-sort-and-limit-with-mongoose

how do i close the topic please? your solution is perfect for me

While @cmgchess already provided the perfect solution in a comment, I would like to discuss the different interpretations of the requirement for the case that we have a tie.
Consider potential case like:
[
  {
    "played_frequency": 1
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 2
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 3
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 4
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 5
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 6
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 7
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 8
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 9
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 10
  },
  {
    "played_frequency": 10
  }
]

So you can see there are 9 cases with played_frequency from 1 to 9, and 2 cases for 10.
If you just want to return 10 documents, i.e. two 10 and from 9 to 2, you can use $rank to compute the rank and select rank: {$lte: 10}
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "played_frequency": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": {
        "$lte": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  }
])

Mongo Playground

If you want to get documents with top 10 played_frequency values, i.e. two 10s and from 9 to 1, you need to use $denseRank
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "played_frequency": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$denseRank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": {
        "$lte": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Nice approach, specifically, raising the question about what to do in case of ties. However, worth noting that both solutions will give more than 10 documents if only using the ranking. In these examples, I've used extra 7's to mess up the output: 1. Mongo Playground for first pipeline with 12 docs. 2. Mongo Playground for second pipeline with 19 docs. So when using this approach, additional checks/modifications will be needed in the application code which uses these pipelines.

To be clear about my comment: I would either (A) add another sort field which serves as a tie-breaker or (B) do it the way Ray suggests in this answer - so that further logic can be applied in application code, to display ties, etc. Though I would group them by rank to make it easier to process in the app.

yes, i understand perfectly, this is amazing, thank you for pointing this out. so another question I have though is, say i was lazy fetching these, and i am skipping 10 documents per fetch, i think this sorting would affect the results returned

@aneroid yes, your concerns are valid. I seem to derail from the requirement of the 10 documents, but opting to get documents with top 10 values. I would suggest OP just stick with cmgchess' simple and elegant solution from this perspective.

@user3118363 the case you mentioned looks like pagination to me. You can simply adjust the $match cause to wrangle with rank 's range to fetch documents. It could potentially be more efficient than using $skip operator. However, I would say for the reason of simplicity, sticking with cmgchess' solution would be the best option.

Okay. So going with cmghess solution, i can chain a skip(int) after the limit()?

@user3118363 certainly. Just make sure you build an index on the played_frequency field to improve sorting performance.

how do i do that please ?
